# What is the best practice to roll out a new version in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

When we switch the server code to a new version in google app engine console, lots of new instances need to be spawned. Because of that, we see some 500 errors and long response time.

What is the best practice to mitigate those problems?

Answer (score 2):

500 responses have not always occurred to requests during a deployment. Previously the new version of your app was able to take over traffic from the old without interruption, however that seemed to stop quite some time ago. These 500s don't appear to go to your application at all (as in no requests will show in your logs, and they won't be served by your applications 500 page). The time window also seems to vary from between none, to up to a minute.

I'm not aware of any indication that the appengine team is looking at solving this, although it seems like a bug (or at the least a reasonable feature request).

To get around this issue, we generally deploy to a different version and switch that to be the default version. Once that is serving traffic, we deploy to the previous version, then switch it back to default. This allows customers to be served uninterrupted, but it does require (at least in java land) a new build.

Comment: We did the same thing ( deploy to a new version, warm up the new version and switch it to the default version ). But 500 errors still show up from time to time during deployment.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other persons answer re: warmup requests, you should also look at traffic splitting - "App Engine's Traffic Splitting tool allows you to roll out features for your app slowly over a period of time, similar to what Google does when rolling out a new feature over a few days or weeks. Traffic Splitting also allows you to do A/B Testing. Traffic Splitting works by splitting incoming requests to different versions of your app."

docs here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting

Comment: We did it too. But it doesn't fix the 500 errors which seems like an app engine bug. ( Nick has more detail about it )

Answer (score 0):

Set up warmup requests to load your application before actual traffic is directed to the instance:

Python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests

Java: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests

Go: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Inbound_Services

PHP: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests

Comment: We already did this. I think App engine has bugs as Nick pointed out.